# PyQt5: fine-grained control of column size in QTableView

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Let's say that I have a table with three column: the sizes of the first two columns are unknown and should expand if there is available space and the sizes of the last column is known and fixed. Since I am already subclassing `QTableView` and `QTableModel`, I figured that subclassing `QHeaderView` is probably the way to go, here is the MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, parent: QObject=None):

        super().__init__(parent)

        self.entries = [
              ['row0, col0 (expanding)', 'row0, col1 (expanding)', 'row0, col2']
            , ['row1, col0 (expanding)', 'row1, col1 (expanding)', 'row1, col2']
            , ['row2, col0 (expanding)', 'row2, col1 (expanding)', 'row2, col2']
        ]

    def headerData(
        self
        , section    : int
        , orientation: Qt.Orientation
        , role       : Qt.ItemDataRole=Qt.DisplayRole
    ):
        if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            return QVariant()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if section == 0:
                return 'Expanding 0'
            if section == 1:
                return 'Expanding 1'
            if section == 2:
                return 'Fixed 0'

            return 'Fix Your Columns'

    def data(
        self
        , index: QModelIndex=QModelIndex()
        , role : Qt.ItemDataRole=Qt.DisplayRole
    ):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        return self.entries[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.entries)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.entries[0])


class MyTableView(QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent: QObject=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


class MyHeaderView(QHeaderView):

    def __init__(
        self
        , orientation: Qt.Orientation=Qt.Horizontal
        , parent     : QWidget=None
    ):
        super().__init__(orientation, parent)

        Stretch, Fixed = QHeaderView.Stretch, QHeaderView.Fixed
        self.SECTION_RESIZE_MODES = [Stretch, Stretch, Fixed]

    def column(self) -> int:
        return 3

    def setModel(self, model: QAbstractItemModel=None):

        super().setModel(model)

        # This loop is the only reason why I am overwriting setModel
        # It adds column behaviour once the model is in place
        for i, mode in enumerate(self.SECTION_RESIZE_MODES):
            self.setSectionResizeMode(i, mode)


class MyCentralWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent: QObject=None):

        super().__init__(parent)

        self.my_table_model = MyTableModel(parent=parent)

        self.my_table_view = MyTableView(parent=parent)
        self.my_header_view = MyHeaderView(parent=parent)

        self.my_table_view.setModel(self.my_table_model)
        self.my_header_view.setModel(self.my_table_model)

        self.my_table_view.setHorizontalHeader(self.my_header_view)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.my_table_view)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent: QObject=None):

        super().__init__(parent)

        self.central_widget = MyCentralWidget(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MyMainWindow()
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Ultimately, it does what I want: the table occupies the whole available horizontal space, the last column is of fixed width and the first two share the available space 50/50. However, this setup is very sensitive to when `.setModel` is called on the `MyTableView` and on the `MyHeaderView`:

The following order in `MyCentralWidget` causes a segmentation fault:

```
    self.my_table_view = MyTableView(parent=parent)
    self.my_header_view = MyHeaderView(parent=parent)

    self.my_table_view.setHorizontalHeader(self.my_header_view)

    self.my_table_view.setModel(self.my_table_model)
    self.my_header_view.setModel(self.my_table_model)
```

So, you can't set the header on the table view before you set the same model to both. Also, if I move the `self.setSectionResizeMode(i, mode)` loop from the `setModel` into the constructor then the segmentation error will happen again (probably because the model is still not set at that point).

Bottomline: this is very fragile. What is a more reliable/robust way to create tables with complex column logic? Also, I do not want any view-specific setup happen in the `MyCentralWidget`. That widget, in my opinion, should create/combine a couple objects and send them into the layout...

Comment: is `self.central_widget = MCentralWidget(self)` or `self.central_widget = MyCentralWidget(self)`?

Comment: @eyllanesc fixed to `MyCentralWidget`, was a misprint